# Throwing exception from constructor?

Tags: c#, exceptions

I have this NamePath class that accepts a string from some system path and tries to split it into two properties, Name and LastName.

Is the code example below fine? I've read that throwing exceptions in constructor is okay, but is there a better way for this case?

```
public class NamePath{
   public string Name {get; private set; }
   public string LastName { get; private set; }

   public NamePath(string path){   
       Parse(path);
   }
   private void Parse(string path){
       if ( ParsingOkay() ) {
          // set the properties
       } else {
          throw new Exception
       }
   }

}
```

I've thought of another approach where NamePath is just data class, and I would have a static method on another class that would try to create NamePath object or else it would return null.

```
public class NamePath {
   public string Name {get; private set; }
   public string LastName { get; private set; }

   public NamePath (string name, string lastName){
       Name = name;
       LastName = lastName;
   }
}

public class PathHelper {
    public static NamePath ParseNamePath (string path){
        if ( ParsingOkay() ){
           return new NamePath
        } else {
           return null
        }
    }
}
```

*code example is semi-pseudo*

Comment: “I've read that throwing exceptions in constructor is okay”: okay as would it compile, or okay as it's a really great idea to have exceptions all over your constructors for better code maintainance? It will compile, indeed, but this doesn't mean you should do that. [Constructors are fine when they contain short, simple code.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/253256/6605) And more precisely, [constructors shouldn't throw exceptions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/201714/6605).

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko: How do you deal with unrecoverable conditions if your constructors can't throw?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: exactly like you wrote in your answer: by using a factory. It doesn't belong to a constructor to parse anything: parsing belongs to a dedicated method, or even a dedicated class if the parsing is overly complex. .NET Framework is a great example of that: you don't do `new DateTime("2020-06-06")`; instead, you use the static method `DateTime.Parse`, and the constructor remains very basic.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko Hiding the problem behind yet another layer of code simply hides the problem and delays fixing it.  And doesn't DateTime.Parse still throw the same exception???

Comment: "constructors shouldn't throw exceptions" - this is a contentious opinion. Many others, such as myself disagree.

Comment: @user949300 To directly quote [Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/), "...it is in no way exceptional for the parse to fail". `Parse` methods produce what Eric very aptly calls "vexing" exceptions. Again, as Eric puts it "`This unfortunate design decision was so vexing that of course the frameworks team implemented TryParse shortly thereafter which does the right thing.`". When you say "`hiding the problem behind yet another layer...`", what problem are you referring to? That user input is, at times, inconsistent? This is not a problem programmers can fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Throwing exceptions in constructors in C# is fine, but a constructor should always create a valid object. I prefer to keep construction devoid of parsing. Parsing is inherently tricky, because you cannot trust the source of the data. Exceptions should be expected when parsing anything. The .NET stack already has a pattern to deal with this: Parse and TryParse.

While a monad is more idiomatic across languages, the [Try]Parse pattern is a long standing idiom for C#.

The constructor always takes data in the necessary pieces, and throws ArgumentXExceptions in the case invalid arguments are passed. The parse methods can be static methods to handle the parsing either by creating a valid object or throwing a FormatException.

```
var path = new NamePath(name, lastName); // throws Argument*Exception

try
{
    var path = NamePath.Parse("...");

    // Use properly constructed path
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    // Parse errors
}

if (NamePath.TryParse("...", out NamePath path))
{
    // User properly constructed NamePath as path variable
}
else
{
    // Parse errors
}
```

This gives code authors some options with how to construct, parse and recover from errors. You'll see this pattern reflected in the native .NET types DateTime, int, decimal, etc. Your custom NamePath type will feel more natural to deal with along side the built-in types:

```
if (int.TryParse("...", out int age))
{
    // valid int
}
else
{
    // invalid int
}

if (NamePath.TryParse("...", out NamePath path))
{
    // valid NamePath
}
else
{
    // invalid NamePath
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Let us assume the caller doesn't need more information than if the parsing failed or not (for whatever reason). Then functionally both of your examples are mostly equivalent. The question you need to ask here then is: how would you prefer to **use** the feature for constructing `NamePath`? Would you prefer to write

```
   try
   {
      var namePath = new NamePath(path);
      // some code using namePath
      // ...
   }
   catch(SomeException ex)
   {
       // do some error handling here
   }
```

Or would you prefer to write

```
      var namePath = PathHelper.ParseNamePath(path);
      if(namePath==null)
      {
           // some error handling here
      }
      // some code using namePath
```

If the error handling in the second case is always to throw an exception, then it should be clear that the first variant would make more sense and become more consise.

Note in both cases, if one forgets the error handling, in the first case the outer scope may get a more specific exception, in the second case the outer scope may get a "null reference exception".

Nevertheless, both variants can be used to write correctly working code, and they don't have a huge difference in maintainability and readability. Hence, it stays to be a judgement call.

Answer (score 4):

Words like "OK" or "better" are meaningless unless you can define what those terms mean for your specific software application.  The way you do that is you ask: "why?"

OK.  So why would you throw from a constructor?

In these situations, it can be useful to determine what your possible options are, and then evaluate each one.

1. You can throw, or
2. You can allow the constructor to return an incomplete object.

That's about it, if you want to use a constructor.  If you can use something other than a constructor, like a factory method, you can return a more sophisticated object like a Maybe Monad.  Maybe that's your "better" way.

But let's say you're not there yet.  You just want to know whether or not to throw in a constructor.

The way you choose between those two options is to determine if there's more than one way for the constructor call to fail.  Because if there's more than one way for it to fail, you're not going to know which way it failed if you don't throw. because that approach doesn't transmit any specific information about the failure, and you're left with an invalid object without knowing why it is invalid.

And this is why it's desirable to throw in a constructor.  When you throw, you can communicate information about why the constructor call failed, and you prevent incomplete objects from being created.

Using a factory method to return null on construction failure does prevent incomplete objects from being created, but communicates no information about why the failure occurred.

---

I should probably mention that, if your constructor throws exceptions, you're going to have significant performance problems if you do something like parse a file in a tight loop using objects created via constructor calls.  Exceptions are expensive, and your parsing operation will grind to a halt if the file you are parsing is not well-formed.

Comment: I will look into the Maybe Monad

Comment: Check out Doc Brown's alternate code in his answer instead.  It's superior for reasons that have nothing to do with throwing exceptions in constructors.

Answer (score 3):

All exceptions are not created equal. Exceptions need to be **exceptional** and your code needs to be concise, readable, and you need to be able to *reason about your code*.

Of course, you can throw anything you like in your constructors. Or you can avoid throwing. The question is... **do you have a plan**? Writing code is, in a way, like writing a story. You have infinite options, dozens of which are almost identical or equivalent. Why am I saying that? Because when you think of your code as a part of reality, you can exploit your mental capacity of grasping concepts and ideas from real life and translate them to code. And then you can be more productive because you think in patterns.

Allow me to suggest a plan: Consumers of your code should be able to *skip the instructions* to the farthest extent possible.

- The only information you can safely convey to consumers of your constructors, and be sure that they will understand it, know about it, and even expect it, is that it **puts the pieces together** and **ensures structural integrity**, i.e. if the constructor is successful, the instance of the object is ready for use!

Be **extra careful** that you understand exactly what "*structural*" means. Structural integrity is what you have when things are in place and they are what they say they are. Having a null value instead of a valid instance spoils structural integrity. Having an empty string **does not inherently do so** because it's still a valid string. You can obviously choose to rule empty or whitespace strings out (as the BCL team decided when they made the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` and `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` methods, because empty and whitespace strings are often as good as null values) but that's that. All other string instances still don't inherently spoil structural integrity. Additional rules about what you want to count as a valid string is information you just **cannot cleanly convey through a constructor**.

Apart from this information, there is nothing, really, that you can convey to the consumers of your constructors without actually *getting them to read the instructions*, **your instructions**. So, in order to **spare them the instructions**, you can simply avoid doing anything more specialized in a constructor. So, to keep constructors **trivial to execute**, you have to:

1. Only throw `ArgumentNullException`s and `ArgumentException`s by checking for `null` or empty strings.
2. Only make assignments to members.
3. Make sure any clever tricks you do in there **don't really matter much**.

This is really just the principle of least astonishment at work. When I retrieve a property of an object, I don't expect it to take more than a trivial amount of time. Same goes for a constructor, otherwise, the consumer will be caught by surprise.

Now, read Eric Lippert's terrific article on [vexing exceptions](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). Then, you will know that, whenever our code does actually stubmle upon an `ArgumentNullException` in a constructor, it's not the user screwing up, it's **us**. These "guard" checks are there to ensure that when we screw up in passing our arguments, we find it out as soon as possible, i.e. upon construction. In production, these guard checks are never expected to throw at all, except if something goes **extraordinarily wrong**.

One thing that experience teaches is that this is a pattern consumers can very easily get their heads over. Consumers almost always know in advance and expect that they cannot *trick* constructors into (or simply fall unknowingly into the trap of) creating problematic instances by passing `null` values. Beyond that, all dependencies passed into a constructor will be valid, simply by virtue of having been constructed **themselves**.

Sometimes, you need to do special things to create an instance, because that's life. Again, the consumer cannot know that you need to *parse* something to create an instance. Spare them the instructions of how to use the constructor. Make the constructor private, and create a static *factory method* that prepares the arguments and constructs the object or fails. Name the method `Parse` or `TryParse` if you need to provide a fail-safe. Now consumers know what is going on... the construction of this object takes some *processing*, and, as a result, it is **not entirely trivial** (and how could it be, since you need to create the object from a string, a **notoriously flexible type**). This way, consumers will *get the message* that you may throw specialized exceptions, or just fail for whatever reason, and they will take precautions.

Also, mind [Robert Harvey's excellent advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/411119/340885) about the performance cost of exceptions in constructors. Make sure you provide two options, one of which just doesn't care, skips exceptions and fails non-exceptionally. Otherwise, make sure you have some good use for the painfully collected stack traces. All the comments about how exceptions are useful are fine, but do you really care about the stack trace or you simply want to show a fancy message to your users about what they are *probably* doing wrong? If so, just create an enumeration of a couple of reasons you know could go wrong and output them together in case of failure. Exceptions **hurt**.

Your second code example seems mostly OK. However, I suggest throwing away the `PathHelper`, it's just expanding the codebase for no good reason (unless you want to make extension methods, which would not be that bad an idea, but then you have to keep the constructor public, to make it accessible outside the class and this defeats the purpose of protecting consumers from invalid instances). Place the method **inside** the NamePath class, close to where it **matters**.

```
public class NamePath
{
   public string Name {get; private set; }
   public string LastName { get; private set; }

   //Now I can have the constructor private, because I don't want
   //anyone to ever write (e.g.):
   //new NamePath("Humphrey", "Bogart");
   //or they will get some bad behavior in other places of the code
   //where it is assumed that NamePath instances are reasonable and
   //have been created properly.
   private NamePath (string name, string lastName)
   {
       Name = name;
       LastName = lastName;
   }

   public static bool TryParsePath(string path, out NamePath output)
   {
       if (ParsingOkay())
       {
           //create instance and assign to output
           return true;
       }

       output = null;
       return false;
   }
}
```

Now, after you have put everything in place, think about the following two lines of code:

- `new NamePath(myPath);`
- `bool parseSuccessful = NamePath.TryParse(myPath, out NamePath namePath, out ParseErrors potentialParseErrors);`

Would you prefer to consume the first or the second version? How would you feel as a consumer, if you knew that the two are equivalent (only you have to catch a couple of exceptions in the first case)? How would you feel as a consumer if you just had `NamePath` class with a constructor, and you had to *dive into the instructions* to find out if anything special takes place in the constructor, which you have to watch out for? Would you be prepared to do that for every object constructor you come across within a library?

## Take-home message

Try to avoid constructing objects from strings when those strings play a special role for the object and need to have a specific format. Write concise methods that make the consumer feel **adequate unease** to guard themselves and/or read the instructions. Make consumers feel at ease when just calling constructors... any constructors.

In short, there is no special reason to throw or not to throw specific exceptions in a constructor (other than the structural integrity ensuring ones, i.e. `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentException`). It is just a **consistent plan**, the simplest one, really, to *not perform additional logic and, as a result, not throw any more specialized exceptions at all*. It reduces entropy, it is more productive, easier to follow, and requires a lot less guesswork from the consumer perspective.